# Remote desktop session not picking up the extra tray in my printer

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003-r2

We have a Brother HL-5340D printer with an extra tray installed.

The driver is configured locally and is working with the extra tray.
However, when I connect into the server (which has the same driver installed), the server
is not able to print to the other tray and the printing preferences do not actually show it either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Some printer drivers let you choose which optional features are actually installed on a given printer; this needs to be configured properly in order for the features' options to even show up in the printing preferences; they can usually be configured in the driver's advanced properties, or something like that.

If this is your case, you should make sure not only the driver is the same between the client and the server, but also its (advanced) configuration.

Comment: The optional tray is correctly configured.  Only the driver is installed on the windows 2003 server.

Comment: What Massimo means is to go to the printer driver on the server, and check the advanced configuration option to see if there is someplace where you can tell the driver that you have the extra tray installed.  In my installation, we use copiers as printers, and if I tell the driver that the stapler is installed I can choose to staple my print jobs,  if I don't set the configuration in the driver, then stapling is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Some redirected printers do not give you access to certain driver properties because the user does not have "Manage this printer" permissions on the print queue. The security cannot be changed.

I created a PowerShell script that will re-create the printer giving you "Manage this printer" access.

https://github.com/zniezelski/Printerceptor/releases

some other solutions are:

- use easy print driver
- Configure printer locally
- Configure printer over IPP

hope this helps someone,

Zach